# PHP upload file not working right

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

I have this script that is uploading file to directory and form data to database. But some how the file is not uploading and says the
variable '$filedestination' is undefined.

```
if(!isset($error)){

try{

  if(isset($_FILES['cv'])){
    $file = $_FILES['cv'];

    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $allowed = array('pdf', 'doc');

    $cl_name = e($_POST['cl_name']);

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)){
      if($file_error === 0){
        $new_file_name = 'cv-'.$cl_name.'-'.$file_ext;
        $file_destination = 'cv/' . $new_file_name;

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){

        } else{
          $error[] = 'No se podido subir el c.v.';
        }
      }else{
        $error[] = 'Problema';
      }
    }
  }

  $handler = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO work_with_us (work_area, cl_name, cl_last_name, cl_dir, cl_city, cl_provincia, cl_tel, cl_email, work_comentario, is_cv, cv_url) VALUES (:work_area, :cl_name, :cl_last_name, :cl_dir, :cl_city, :cl_provincia, :cl_tel, :cl_email, :work_com, :is_cv, :cv_url)');

  $handler->execute(array(
    ':work_area' => e($_POST['work_area']),
    ':cl_name' => e($_POST['cl_name']),
    ':cl_last_name' => e($_POST['cl_last_name']),
    ':cl_dir' => e($_POST['cl_dir']),
    ':cl_city' => e($_POST['cl_city']),
    ':cl_provincia' => e($_POST['cl_provincia']),
    ':cl_tel' => (int)$_POST['cl_tel'],
    ':cl_email' => e($_POST['cl_email']),
    ':work_com' => e($_POST['work_comentario']),
    ':is_cv' => 'Si',
    ':cv_url' => $file_destination
  ));

}catch(PDOException $e){
  $error[] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

}

Thing is i have the same script used, in other file and for uploading pictures and it works fine but this one for .pdf and .doc its somehow not working.

Comment: try initializing `$file_destination` to blank in the beginning of try block. `$file_destination = '';` Also add `png` and `doc` options in `$allowed` array to make it work for .png and .doc files

Answer (score 1):

You are only allowing pdf and doc :

```
 $allowed = array('pdf', 'doc');
```

So png is not allowed. As for the word file, make sure you are uploading a `.doc` file and not a `.docx` since it will not be allowed. You can add a list of allowed extensions that covers all Microsoft word extensions.

As for Microsoft extensions, check [this link](http://www.file-extensions.org/filetype/extension/name/microsoft-office-files).

Comment: Well, it think you got my description wrong. I used pdf in this script and its not working. I have the same script in other file for pictures and its working. and it did typo for .pdf and .doc

Comment: what does `in_array($file_ext, $allowed)` return?

Comment: its not returning no error. just
       Notice: Undefined variable: file_destination in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/reparo/work_with_us.php on line 79

Comment: Try to make some debugging, check the value of `$file_ext` and the value of `$new_file_name`.

Answer (score 0):

just define your $filedestination variable globally means out of if block. Your Code is OK. 
Give R/W permission to the folder in which you want to move/upload your file.
Actually due to R/W permission your file is not moving try Chmod command for giving R/W permission ; if you are working on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if there is any content in `$error` or check `$error` variable value...

my another suggestion is rather than to check `$file['error']`,

check `(getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]!==false)`

Comment: If it's not giving you any error value then go to my another suggestion and then let me know what problem you are facing!!!!

Comment: if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)){
      if($file_error === 0){
        $new_file_name = 'cv-'.$cl_name.'-'.$file_ext;
        $file_destination = 'cv/' . $new_file_name;

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){

        } else{
          $error[] = 'No se podido subir el c.v.';
        }
      }else{
        $error[] = 'Problema';
      }
    }
else
{
    $error[]="Not going in first loop"
}

Now check the value of error

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that a folder named 'cv' exists in your localserver.

And, I just noticed in your code:
`$new_file_name = 'cv-'.$cl_name.'-'.$file_ext;`

You will have an output like this: **myfile-doc**

When it is supposed to be: **myfile.doc**

So, I suppose it should be:

```
 $new_file_name = 'cv-'.$cl_name.'.'.$file_ext;
```

I do not know if this could help you but I just notice it.